# Association Form for custom workflow in a subsite

Tags: workflow, form

I have a SP 2010 custom workflow built using Visual Studio 2010. The workflow specifies an association URL like this

```
  <Workflow
     Name="WF Name"
     Description="WF Description"
     Id="51dfe7c0-6433-49e3-9007-25e16e199999"
     AssociationUrl="/Company/WorkflowForms/WorkflowAssociationForm.aspx"
     CodeBesideClass="Company.Workflow"
     CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$">
    <Categories/>
```

When adding this workflow to a list in the site collection root site everything works as expected. However, when I want to add the same workflow to a list in a sub-site of the site collection (E.g. /subsite) then when clicking on the 'Next' button the url */**subsite**/Company/WorkflowForms/WorkflowAssociationForm.aspx* is requested (note the leading /subsite) which does not exist (only /*Company/WorkflowForms/WorkflowAssociationForm.aspx* exists).

Does the workflow WSP need to be installed explicitly for the sub-site, or is there some configuration setting that will make this scenario succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place the WorkflowAssociationForm.aspx page into the **LAYOUTS** folder (~/_layouts/Company/WorkflowForms/WorkflowAssociationForm.aspx). The path to the master page might also need to be adjusted in this case.